# Angular Создание кликабельного списка по топологии Material-design с раскрывающимся на фул скрин окном подробностей

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

На сайте материал дизайна показан пример, который я хотел бы воплотить в жизнь: https://material.io/design/components/lists.html#behavior

Хочу **в вебе** на **Angular** 8 реализовать **кликабельный список айтемов** как в примере. Для этого использовал стандартные элементы:

[List](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview)

[Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Чтобы эмулировать фул-скриновый диалог - я определяю размеры окна и передаю эти размеры диалогу (так как фул-скрин диалог не поддерживается по дефолту у данного элемента в вебе)
Однако **результат выглядит немного не так** как показано в примере.
Данный пример ссылается на [Navigation transitions](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#hierarchical-transitions) 
 где анимация демонстрирует, как должен выглядеть переход (**выбранный элемент должен приподняться над поверхностью и расширится на весь экран**). В моем же случае новое окно просто появляется из центра.
Скорее всего я делаю что-то не так, но я новичок в Angular и в Material-design и возможно просто чего-то еще не знаю, но на просторах сети мне не удалось найти ответа на мой вопрос.

*В моих попытках что-то сделать я все сломал, по этому код сейчас не прикреплю. Чуть позже постараюсь пофиксить и дам ссылку на stackblitz, но предполагаю, что пошел не верным путем*

Возможно ли это вообще в вебе используя стандартные инструменты материал-дизайна? Заранее спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: мне кажется тебе не нужно определять размеры или проделывать какие либо манипуляции с числами. При бутстрапинге компонента через `MatDialog.open` можно передать параметры вторым аргументом. Там есть `minWidth` и `height` - ты можешь попробовать передавать `100%/100%` или `100vw/100vh` - `dialog.open(MoyComponent, { width: ..., height: ... })`. Оверрайдить анимации нельзя, увы так работает Angular

Comment: @overthesanity нет, в этом смысле я все делаю верно так как на мобильных дивайсах 100%/100% или 100vw/100vh работают не совсем корректно. Тут у меня проблем нет. Вопрос больше в том, как сделать этот переход таким как показано в примере на material.io (красиво ведь...)

Comment: я же тебе ответил в последнем предложении